# How to remove the header and footer in React Native WebView? (While Loading)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

I want to remove the header and footer of the website in react native 'WebView'. I tried the Code below and it works.
When the 'WebView' load completely it's ok!

The problem is that while the 'WebView' is loading you can see the header and footer.
How Can i make it work whithout see it at all?

I tried this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import WebView from "react-native-webview";

type Props = {};

const MyWebView: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  
  const runFirst = `
      let header = document.querySelector("header#header-id")

      let footer = document.querySelector("footer#footer-id")

      header.style.display = "none"

      footer.style.display = "none"
   
      true; 
    `;

  return (
    <WebView
      style={{flex: 1}}
      source={{uri: "https://something.com"}}
      injectedJavaScript={runFirst}
      onMessage={event => {
        const {data} = event.nativeEvent;
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default MyWebView;
```